# Android\Java Maven skip build module if no changes

Tags: java, android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I have a few modules in my project

When i execute

> mvn clean install

it will be rebuild all my modules and it will be a long long time.( I know - it was because i execute a `clean` goal)

What the goal i need to **execute or set a PROPERTY in `pom.xml (maybe)`** to say maven do not compile(skip or getting existing SNAPSHOT) module if was no file (no changes) in this module.

Comment: the intention of clean is to rebuild everything.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker after few hours of googling i say you not right, because **clean goal just clean output directory**.

Answer (score 1):

Your build is probably taking a long time because of the tests, not compilation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918165/does-maven-support-incremental-builds).

An easy way of speeding up your build is to [skip tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123075/maven-how-can-i-skip-test-in-some-projects-via-command-line-options).

You can also try [advanced reactor options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076713/why-maven-is-running-tests-again-when-jar-is-already-there) to select which module you want to build.

[Supposedly](http://takari.io/2014/02/03/maven-speed.html) efforts are underway to make Maven do real incremental builds.